MAXSCRIPT numSplines obj cannot refresh after changing their amount
I would love to done something like this
fn cutSegment obj = (
    totalNumer=numSplines obj
    select obj; max modify mode; subObjectLevel=1
    for i=1 to totalNumer do (
        numer=numKnots obj i
        setKnotSelection obj i #(numer, (numer/2)+1)
        splineOps.startBreak $
    ); for i=totalNumer+1 to totalNumer*2 do (
        deleteSpline $ i
    )
)

Where after the first loop, the amount of splines wasn't refresh/reload. So how can i make this in maxscript when I want on the same evaluation work on changed objects?
Maybe i just dont understand this, but i tried every command like updateShape obj but it doesnt work of course
